# Proxim RangeLan 7920 Ethernet Adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, protocol, mac

I have a Proxim RangeLan 7920 Ethernet Adapter.  Does this device have its own IP address or is it a MAC repeater such as a switch/bridge?

How do I connect to it from my laptop via wireless?

Appreciate any help or comments.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [data link layer](http://www.cybarcode.com/proxim/wireless/access_point/openair/7920-05) bridge. It makes itself invisible and [does not modify](http://www.tradeloop.com/computer_parts/detail/?k=7920-05) packets that pass across it. In this sense, it is not like typical WiFi access points and bridges but more like a WDS bridge.

Comment: Appreciated.  How might I go about connecting to it if it is invisible?  And by connecting to it I mean connecting from my laptop to both to the PC it is connected to as well as the device itself to check its settings?

Comment: It's only invisible to packets not addressed to it. Essentially, it's a bridge, and it's also an endpoint device connected to that bridge.